# Check for template part, else filter content

Tags: plugin-development, filters

In a plugin which brings its own post type to the table, I wish to handle `post_meta` by filtering `the_content` - unless the user has provided their own `single-{post-type}.php` template.

Should I run this within `the_content` filter? Or elsewhere?

```
if ( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-event.php' ) ) {
    include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-event.php' );
} elseif ( file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/single-event.php' ) ) {
    include( get_template_directory() . '/single-event.php' );
} else {
    // filter time
}
```

If it's not in my `add_filter('the_content', 'event_filter_function', 10);` then I guess I'm wondering how else I will know at run-time whether this file exists.

So is computationally expensive to run this filter and simply return $content unaltered if there is a template provided? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two code snippets here that are pretty self explanatory:

### Add a template from the plugin if none is present from the theme

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpse110317_append_meta' );
function wpse110317_append_meta( $template )
{
    is_singular()
    AND ! file_exists( get_template_directory()."/{$template}" )
        AND $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."/{$template}";

    return $template;
}
```

### Append something to the content *until* there's a template in the theme

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpse110317_maybe_add_filter' );
function wpse110317_maybe_add_filter( $template )
{
    is_singular()
    AND ! file_exists( get_template_directory()."/{$template}" )
        AND add_action( 'the_content', 'wpse110317_append_meta' );

    return $template;
}
function wpse110317_append_meta( $content )
{
    // do stuff
    return $content;
}
```